# How to create a working ikvmstub for System.Web

Tags: ikvm

I want to create a stub for System.Web and use HttpContext in in my java code and then be able to use it. I have tried the following:

**Folder structure**

- program [folder]

  - ikvm-7.0.4335.0 [folder]
  - compile.bat
  - test.java
  - IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
  - IKVM.Runtime.dll

**The java class test.java**

```
import cli.System.Web.HttpContext;

public class test
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       HttpContext.get_Current().get_Items().get_Item("MyKey");
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**The compilation compile.bat**

```
ikvm-7.0.4335.0\bin\ikvmstub mscorlib
ikvm-7.0.4335.0\bin\ikvmstub System.Web
javac test.java -classpath mscorlib.jar;System.Web.jar
ikvm-7.0.4335.0\bin\ikvmc -target:exe -reference:System.Web.dll test.class
test.exe
pause
```

If I run compile.bat it will output:

> Warning IKVMC0100: class "cli.System.Collections.IDictionary" not
>   found Link Error: Method
>   "cli.System.Web.HttpContext.get_Items()Lcli.System.Collection
>   s.IDictionary;" has a return type "cli.System.Collections.IDictionary,
>   mscorlib,  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" instead of type
>   "cli.System.Collections.IDictionary (unknown assembly)" as expected by
>   "test "

I have also tried to create a stub for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll" directly but then I get this error:

> Error: unable to load assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Micr osoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll' as
>   it depends on a higher version of mscorlib than the one currently
>   loaded

And then I tried to create a stub for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" and got:

> ikvmstub "C:\Program Files ( x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll"
>   Warning: assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framewo rk.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" is
>   ignored as previously loaded assembly "C:
>   \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" has the
>   same identit y "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Has anyone tried this and suceeded?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I had not referenced the mscorlib.dll since I thought it was referenced automatically. So if I change the following line, it works:

> <strike>ikvm-7.0.4335.0\bin\ikvmc -target:exe -reference:System.Web.dll test.class</strike>

to

```
ikvm-7.0.4335.0\bin\ikvmc -target:exe -reference:mscorlib.dll -reference:System.Web.dll test.class
```